# ApexCharts (bar)chart group or cluster dates / bars based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

In Apex Charts, is there a way to cluster or group bars of a 'datetime' bar-chart when zoomed out? Basically I want to use some data like this:

```
  let series = [{
        name: 'Orders',
        data: [
            [1327359600000,1],
            [1327446000000,1],
            [1327532400000,1],

            ...

            [1331766000000,1],
            [1331852400000,1],
            [1332111600000,1],
            [1332198000000,1],
        ],
    }];
```

.. And then have the chart decide how the bars should be distributed and displayed base on the scale of the x-ax.
So when zoomed to 'month-level', group all orders for each month and zooming in to 'day-level' group the orders for each day, etc.

Is it possible or do I need to change/calculate the data based on the zoom level of the chart myself?
Or is there maybe another alternative chart type that can do this?